# Anti-CSRF form Token validation always failed

Tags: php, session, csrf-protection

I've been looking into session security and have read that adding a random generated "token" to a form and validating it upon the submission of the said form can help with CSRF ( Cross-Site Request Forgery ).

So I setup a test using someone else's example to see how it works but it doesn't go well. I've set it so the form is just submitted to the same page but it seems that is causing the whole thing to re-initialize and re-generate the `$token` making it so it will never match as hitting submit will create a new one, immediately invalidating the previous one.

What am I doing wrong? My understanding is as this is a temporary token all I have to do is store it temporarily in the $_SESSION array for comparison to make sure whatever form being submitted is from one source and is the authentic user and not some forgery.

I'm sorry I'm new to PHP Sessions and all the security needed with it so some clarification would be very helpful if I've misunderstood anything.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION['token'])) {
    $_SESSION['token'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
} 
$token = $_SESSION['token'];


if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
    if($_POST['token'] == $token)
    {
        echo $_POST['username'];
    }else
    {
        echo 'Sorry invalid token';
    }
}
 ?>

 <form method="POST" action="">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"><br>
        <input type="text" name="token" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['token'];?>"><br>
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I tested your code, and it worked for me.

Comment: Well I'm glad to hear it actually works as intended. Still can't, for the life of me, get it to work on my side though. 

Looked into the debug again and noticed that after hitting submit my `$_SESSION['token']` becomes empty which is why the `if(empty())` block I setup at the start is firing off and re-generating a new token. I don't know why.